# getElementsByTagName().textContent >>> написать в >>> getElementById.textContent

Tags: javascript, html

Есть отрывок исходного кода:

> `<tr id="file_theme_estimates_rus">
>   <td><span class="five">5</span></td>
>   <td></td>
>   <td><span class="two">2</span></td>
>   <td><span class="three">3</span></td>
>   <td></td>
>   <td></td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>   <td id="file_estimates_rus"></td>
>   </tr>`

Есть неработающая функция Javascript:

> `document.getElementById("file_estimates_rus").textContent = document.getElementById("file_theme_estimates_rus").getElementsByTagName("span").textContent;`

Что надо сделать, чтобы функция Javascript заработала? Нужно, чтобы все элементы `span` появились в строчке `<td id="file_estimates_rus">...</td>`. Т.е. в данном случае, после выполнения функции Javascript, должно получится так:

> `<tr id="file_theme_estimates_rus">
>   <td><span class="five">5</span></td>
>   <td></td>
>   <td><span class="two">2</span></td>
>   <td><span class="three">3</span></td>
>   <td></td>
>   <td></td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>   <td id="file_estimates_rus"><span class="five">5</span><span class="two">2</span><span class="three">3</span></td>
>   </tr>`

Напишите, пожалуйста, функцию Javascript, которая поможет мне это сделать.

Comment: Вы написали уже почти 50 вопросов. Может, уже пора научиться форматировать код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementById("file_estimates_rus"), 
    b = document.getElementById("file_theme_estimates_rus").getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { a.innerHTML += b[i].outerHTML; }
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы цифры шли в другом порядке? Т.е. здесь получается "3 2 5", а можно ли сделать "5 2 3"?

Comment: Здесь получается "5 2 3". Сами посмотрите http://jsfiddle.net/wzwewr6d/1/

Comment: Так всё таки как сделать не "5 2 3", а "3 2 5"?